# Is the 2019 Specialized Diverge meeting sales projections?

Tags: gravel, specialized-bikes

I recently acquired a lower end 2019 Specialized Diverge (carbon fiber) as a frame replacement for a 5 year old cracked Secteur frame (aluminum).  Needless to say, this is a HUGE upgrade for me.

In discussions with local bikers, it has been stated that the Diverge has not met sales projections, and so they are generally over stocked.  (Which would explain the significant upgrade for me.)

I have tried several google searches, but I've never been interested in sales vs. projections before, and all I'm finding are reviews of the diverge (which are favorable).

Comment: Surely such information would be proprietary to Specialized and their dealer network. What the general public would get to know is if Diverge models were being marked down.

Comment: In a more general sense, I've heard from a couple of people (I can't be more specific) recently that sales of road bikes have really been down in the past couple of years and most manufacturers that order on a yearly basis are way overstocked.  I was told that (at least for certain manufacturers) if I wanted a new bike that was in stock in a shop I shouldn't buy it for more than 20% off list.

Comment: @DavidW this may well be true; USA Cycling's member and public surveys do appear to reveal that road racing is declining, so perhaps sales of road bikes are declining also. However, the Diverge is actually a gravel bike. In general, sales of gravel bikes should be increasing. Any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: @WeiwenNg Sorry, don't know if gravel bikes are also suffering, or if they're the reason that road bikes are declining; that wasn't part of the discussion.  My point was just in general that there is a decline in sales across at least some adjacent markets.  Maybe it's "e-bikes" eating into sales of traditional bikes?  I'm seeing a _lot_ more of those around.

Comment: Unless the manufacturer or an agent has figures to share, then this really is going to be speculation and opinion.   Nice bike - I'm envious - just enjoy your win, there are precious few times where the consumer comes out ahead.

Comment: Can someone explain how this question is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have bought several older frames that were set aside as warranty replacement pieces. They were both about 5 years old when I got them. Nashbar stated at the time, the factory released them for resale as they were no longer needed. Nashbar used to sell them deeply discounted. In your case I can think of a few scenarios. 1. So many Secteur frames failed that they ran out of replacements. 2. They found a defect and the product run period included the spares they set aside. 3. You ride an uncommon size and it was unavailable. 4. Someone made a big mistake. Of course all this is speculation. Just enjoy your good fortune.